# how to minimize iterm2 window when closed using red window button

Tags: mac, iterm

Whenever I click on the close window button (red), it closes my current iterm2 window, then when I click on iterm2 in my dock again, it opens a new one (I suppose), my entire iterm2 prompt is gone, and I don't want it.

I just want it (red button) to minimize my iterm2 window (yellow button behavior).

how do I do that ?

PS: no closing option is enabled[image]

Comment: Not really. This is macOS behaviour for those buttons. In this case I would use the keyboard cmd-h to hide the window

Comment: it is not a macOS behavior, before i installed oh my zsh and p10k, when ever I did click on the red button to close the terminal, it just made it disapeared without the "effect", and when I clicked on it again on my dock, it would open it backup without refreshing it. but since I installed iterm2, it happens with my basic terminal too, and I don't now why.

Comment: Red Button = close/quit process [not entire app]. That's how it's supposed to behave. There's a minimise button for minimising & Cmd/h or opt/click a new app to hide the frontmost app.

Comment: The apple supplied startup zsh scripts will recover some of what the last zsh session did. Perhaps you aren't calling them. Delete your zsh srtup scripts and see

Comment: Just a tought: why not set system-wide hotkey for iTerm? No need to hide or click anything, 100% keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin, it looks like you might not have the latest version. Since I have some options you don't (from your screenshot).

[image: Screenshot of iTerm's Preferences > General > Closing]

I believe to solve your problem you need to head over to your profile and go to the session tab. You'll see options at the top to adjust closing behavior.

[image: Screenshot of iTerm's Preferences > Profiles > Session]

If that doesn't work, you may need to uninstall iTerm and re-install it. I had an issue where iTerm would crash whenever the `sudo` password was needed. It would then open other iTerm windows **and** the terminal and get stuck in a loop until I force quit both of them. So I think sometimes the shell integration gets funky and out of whack.

Comment: please use [Stack Exchange's imgur installation for images](https://stack.imgur.com/).